# Query string will not map to action videmode?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, query-string, viewmodel

I have the following Control action :

```
public ActionResult List(ListPostViewModel data)
{
     return View(data);
}
```

The ViewModel looks like this :

```
public class ListPostViewModel
    {
        public ListPostViewModel()
        {
            PLS = new PostListSettings();
        }

        public PostListSettings PLS;
    }
```

And this is the other part of the ViewModel :

```
public class PostListSettings
    {
        public PostListSettings()
        {
            P = 1;
            CP = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AmountOfPostsPerPage"].ToString());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Amount of ads on one page
        /// </summary>
        public int CP { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// CurrentPage
        /// </summary>
        public int P { get; set; }
    }
```

In previous projects I could send a URL like this : `http://MyComputer/?PLS.P=2` and get the ListPostViewModel.PLS.P set to 2 but its not working in my new ASP.NET MVC 4 solution? Why?

The only rout I got is the default one :

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "List", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `PostListSettings` to property like this:

```
public class ListPostViewModel
{
    public ListPostViewModel()
    {
        PLS = new PostListSettings();
    }

    public PostListSettings PLS { get; set; }
}
```